# How to pass list elements to model in R?

Tags: r, list

I am quite new to the use of *lists* so I apologize if this problem may sound very dumb.

From an original set of 459,046 customers, I have created a function that splits and stores the base in several elements of a list.

```r
sampled_list <- baseSample(dataset = clv_df_cbs, sample.size = 10000, seed = 12345)
```

Executing this function (**baseSample**) you will get a new object list, containing mutually exclusive groups of customers (each group will be made of 10,000 customers - apart from the last one who may be smaller, depending on the initial volume)

```
> sampled_list <- baseSample(dataset = clv_df_cbs, sample.size = 10000, seed = 12345)
[1] "Seed: 12345"
[1] "Total groups created: 46"
[1] "Group size: 10000"
```

In this case, the output is a list of 46 elements stored in the object called **sample_list**.

Now, I want to pass each of these 46 elements to a BTYD model that will forecast the number of transactions in the next 90 days (given the learnings from the input).

The reason why I cannot pass the full dataset to the BTYD model is because this model heavily uses mcmc, therefore there is a long time of calculation that stops the model to provide any output. So I have decided to generate forecasts running the same model several times (on sample big enough) until I manage to pass all the base as model input.

The operations that need to be performed on each of the elements are the following

```r
# Estimate parameters for element1 of the list
pggg.draws1 <- pggg.mcmc.DrawParameters(element1, 
                                           mcmc = 1000, # number of MCMC steps
                                           burnin = 250, # number of initial MCMC steps which are discarded
                                           thin = 10, # only every thin-th MCMC step will be returned
                                           chains = 2, # number of MCMC chains to be run
                                           trace = 50) # print logging step every trace iteration

# generate draws for holdout period
pggg.xstar.draws1 <- mcmc.DrawFutureTransactions(element1, pggg.draws1)

# conditional expectations
element1$xstar.pggg <- apply(pggg.xstar.draws1, 2, mean)

# P(active)
element1$pactive.pggg <- mcmc.PActive(pggg.xstar.draws1)

# P(alive)
element1$palive.pggg <- mcmc.PAlive(pggg.draws1)

# show estimates for first few customers
head(element1[, c("x", "t.x", "x.star",
                            "xstar.pggg", "pactive.pggg", "palive.pggg")],50)

# report median cohort-level parameter estimates
round(apply(as.matrix(pggg.draws1$level_2), 2, median), 3)

# report mean over median individual-level parameter estimates
median.est1 <- sapply(pggg.draws1$level_1, function(draw) {
  apply(as.matrix(draw), 2, median)
})
round(apply(median.est1, 1, mean), 3)
```

Ideally, the output should be stored straight into a new data.frame - so I can retrieve the Id and the forecast (amongst other stuff originally included in the dataset).

Here below some mock data to play with from a publicly available dataset.

```r
library(BTYDplus)
library(tidyverse)
data("groceryElog")
dataset<-elog2cbs(groceryElog, T.cal = "2006-12-01") 


# FUNCTION baseSample ####
baseSample <- function(dataset, sample.size, seed=NULL) {
  seed.value <- if(is.null(seed)) {
    as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(),"%Y"))*10000+as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(),"%m"))*100+as.numeric(format(Sys.Date(),"%d"))
  } else {
    seed
  }

  set.seed(seed.value)

  # RE-ORDER DATA FRAME (SAME LENGTH)
  data <- with(dataset, dataset[order(sample(cust, nrow(dataset))),])

  # BUILD A LIST OF DFs 
  set.sample.size <- sample.size
  data$cycles_group <- paste0("sample_", ceiling(1:nrow(data)/set.sample.size))

  df_list <- split(data, data$cycles_group)

  print(paste0("Seed: ", seed.value))
  print(paste0("Total groups created: ", length(unique(data$cycles_group))))
  print(paste0("Group size: ", set.sample.size))
  return(df_list)
  #print(df_list)
}

# ** OUTPUT: Base split in lists ####
sampled_list <- baseSample(dataset = dataset, sample.size = 100, seed = 12345)
```

Thanks

Comment: You can do this in base R by wrapping all those operations in a function inside a call to `lapply`, then using something like `newdf <- do.call(rbind, [list outputted by lapply])` to roll the results up into a new data frame.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comment. Can you be a bit more specific, please? If you consider the last chunk of script (the example), how can you create the [list outputted by lapply] you mentioned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In base R, you can use `lapply` to iterate a function over the elements of a list and return a new list with the results of those iterations. After using your example code to generate a list called `sampled_list`...

```
# turn the code for the operations you want to perform on each list element into a function,
# with a couple of minor tweaks
thingy <- function(i) {

  # Estimate parameters for element1 of the list
  pggg.draws1 <- pggg.mcmc.DrawParameters(i, 
                                          mcmc = 1000, # number of MCMC steps
                                          burnin = 250, # number of initial MCMC steps which are discarded
                                          thin = 10, # only every thin-th MCMC step will be returned
                                          chains = 2, # number of MCMC chains to be run
                                          trace = 50) # print logging step every trace iteration

  # generate draws for holdout period
  pggg.xstar.draws1 <- mcmc.DrawFutureTransactions(i, pggg.draws1)

  # conditional expectations
  i$xstar.pggg <- apply(pggg.xstar.draws1, 2, mean)

  # P(active)
  i$pactive.pggg <- mcmc.PActive(pggg.xstar.draws1)

  # P(alive)
  i$palive.pggg <- mcmc.PAlive(pggg.draws1)

  # show estimates for first few customers [commenting out for this iterated version]
  # head(element1[, c("x", "t.x", "x.star", "xstar.pggg", "pactive.pggg", "palive.pggg")],50)

  # report median cohort-level parameter estimates
  round(apply(as.matrix(pggg.draws1$level_2), 2, median), 3)

  # report mean over median individual-level parameter estimates
  median.est1 <- sapply(pggg.draws1$level_1, function(draw) {
    apply(as.matrix(draw), 2, median)
  })

  # get the bits you want in a named vector
  z <- round(apply(median.est1, 1, mean), 3)

  # convert that named vector of results into a one-row data frame to make collapsing easier
  data.frame(as.list(z))

}

# now use lapply to iterate that function over the elements of your list
results <- lapply(sampled_list, thingy)

# now bind the results into a data frame
boundresults <- do.call(rbind, results)
```

Results (which took a while to get):

```
              k lambda    mu          tau    z
sample_1  4.200  0.174 0.091      102.835 0.27
sample_10 3.117  0.149 0.214      128.143 0.29
sample_11 4.093  0.154 0.115      130.802 0.30
sample_12 4.191  0.142 0.053      114.108 0.33
sample_13 2.605  0.155 0.071      160.743 0.35
sample_14 9.196  0.210 0.084      111.747 0.36
sample_15 2.005  0.145 0.091      298.872 0.40
sample_16 2.454  0.111 0.019 78731750.121 0.70
sample_2  2.808  0.138 0.059      812.278 0.40
sample_3  4.327  0.166 0.116      559.318 0.42
sample_4  9.266  0.166 0.038      146.283 0.40
sample_5  3.277  0.157 0.073      105.915 0.33
sample_6  9.584  0.184 0.086      118.299 0.31
sample_7  4.244  0.189 0.118       54.945 0.23
sample_8  4.388  0.147 0.085      325.054 0.36
sample_9  7.898  0.181 0.052       83.892 0.33
```

You can also combine those last two steps into a single line of `do.call(rbind, lapply(...))`. If you want to make the row names in the results table into a column, you could do `boundresults$sample <- row.names(boundresults)` after making that table. And if you don't like creating new objects in your environment, you could put that function inside the call to `lapply`, i.e., `lapply(sampled_list, function(i) { [your code] }).`

Comment: Outstanding explanation. I'll play a bit with apply and its variants. Thank you very much.